# TypeScript: Specify the interface of the static part of an export class?

Tags: typescript

I tried to use the trick under the "[Difference between static/instance side of class](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-class-types)"  section of the Handbook to specify a interface for the static side (i.e. the function) of a class:

```
export interface StaticInterface {
    info: string;
}
class _X {
    static info = 'something';
    ...
}
export var X: StaticInterface = _X;
```

But when I tried to `extend theModule.X` in another file, the compiler says:

```
error TS2305: Module '"..."' has no exported member 'X'.
```

Comment: Can you share a more complete code example so I can see what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example based on the TypeScript Handbook:

```
module Example {
    export interface ClockStatic {
        new (hour: number, minute: number);
    }

    class Clock {
        currentTime: Date;
        constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    }

    export var cs: ClockStatic = Clock;
}

var newClock = new Example.cs(7, 30);
```

It is important that you export the interface, and that the class implements the interface correctly.

Comment: Hi, it seems the key is the constructor definition in the interface. However, The interface I want to use is one that can also be implemented by a normal instance, so this won't really do. The new error is `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

Comment: You probably want to separate out the instance interface and the static interface. For example, perhaps you want it to work like jQuery where the JQueryStatic interface returns an instance that implements the JQuery interface.

Comment: Yes. That would do it. Thanks!