# Using parametrized TypeScript class as a type parameter

Tags: typescript, templates, generics

Recent TypeScript (3.1) has awesome features with type inferences. It find it very useful to be able to do this, with strict type checking:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(a: number, b: string) {}
}

function create<T extends new(...args: any[]) => any>(
    cls: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>): InstanceType<T> {
  return new cls(...args);
}

let a: Foo = create(Foo, 18, "a");   // <-- yay, fully typechecked
```

But I can't find any way to do this when my class is generic (parametrized):

```js
class Bar<T> {
  constructor(a: T, b: string) {}
}

let b = create(Bar, "asdf", "a");          // <--- not typechecked
let c = create(Bar<number>, 20, "a");              // <--- error
let d = create<typeof Bar<number>>(Bar, 20, "a");  // <--- error
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, generic parameter `T` in `Bar<T>` seems to apply only to the instance part of `Bar` and not to the static part, although `T` is used in the constructor signature (and constructor belongs to the static part).

The workaround is to have explicit interface that defines static part, [as suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149029/typescript-specify-the-interface-of-the-static-part-of-an-export-class), and use "higher-order" function `Bar<T>()` instead of a class:

```
function create<T extends new(...args: any[]) => any>(
    cls: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>): InstanceType<T> {
  return new cls(...args);
}


interface BarConstructor<T, C> {
  new(a: T, b: string): C;
}

class BarImpl<T> {
  constructor(a: T, b: string) {}
}

function Bar<T>(): BarConstructor<T, BarImpl<T>> {
  return BarImpl;
}


let b = create(Bar(), "asdf", "a"); // OK because Bar() by itself implies Bar<{}>(),
                                   // and "asdf" is assignable to {}
  // you can turn it into an error by having `never` as default for T like this
  // function Bar<T = never>()

let c = create(Bar<number>(), "asdf", "a"); // error as expected
let d = create(Bar<number>(), 20, "a");    // OK
```